# Load View Controller via code

Tags: objective-c, xcode, view, controller, viewcontroller

I've got my storyboard with several ViewControllers, connected each other via buttons.

Now I need that if a particular condition is true, to load another UIViewController. I managed to do it creating a new subclass, but I would like to avoid it. I just want

```
if(condition == true){
  // load viewcontroller located in the storyboard, not connected with anything else
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I'll elaborate:
Use should use `- (id)instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier` method of `UIStoryBoard` class, but make sure to fill in identifier field of your controller in IB.

```
UIStoryboard *storybrd = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryBrdName" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *mycontroller =[storybrd instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myIdent"];
```

Now you should have your controller and present it as you like.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @mit3z. I'm not sure what's the name of my controller, I created it via the storyboard (as you can see, I'm new to Xcode, so please be kind :P). I gave a name to the controller (myControl), but I'm getting an error.

http://pastebin.com/9qzjTa7L

Comment: thanks again for the reply. Here's what I've got:

    http://pastebin.com/ahw0DeLU

But it doesn't works. What am I doing wrong?